# Half of my ellipse drawn in the wrong place

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, ellipse, bresenham

Here is the code for an oval drawing method I am working on. I am applying the Bresenham method to plot its co-ordinates, and taking advantage of the ellipse's symmetrical properties to draw the same pixel in four different places.

```
void cRenderClass::plotEllipse(int xCentre, int yCentre, int width, int height, float angle, float xScale, float yScale)
{
    if ((height == width) && (abs(xScale - yScale) < 0.005))
        plotCircle(xCentre, yCentre, width, xScale);

    std::vector<std::vector <float>> rotate;
    if (angle > 360.0f)
    {
        angle -= 180.0f;
    }
    rotate = maths.rotateMatrix(angle, 'z');

    //rotate[0][0] = cos(angle)
    //rotate[0][1] = sin(angle)

    float theta = atan2(-height*rotate[0][1], width*rotate[0][0]);
    if (angle > 90.0f && angle < 180.0f)
    {
        theta += PI;
    }

    //add scalation in at a later date

    float xShear = (width * (cos(theta) * rotate[0][0])) - (height * (sin(theta) * rotate[0][1]));
    float yShear = (width * (cos(theta) * rotate[0][1])) + (height * (sin(theta) * rotate[0][0]));
    float widthAxis = abs(sqrt(((rotate[0][0] * width) * (rotate[0][0] * width)) + ((rotate[0][1] * height) * (rotate[0][1] * height))));
    float heightAxis = (width * height) / widthAxis;

    int aSquared = widthAxis * widthAxis;
    int fourASquared = 4*aSquared;
    int bSquared = heightAxis * heightAxis;
    int fourBSquared = 4*bSquared;

    x0 = 0;
    y0 = heightAxis;
    int sigma = (bSquared * 2) + (aSquared * (1 - (2 * heightAxis)));

    while ((bSquared * x0) <= (aSquared * y0))
    {
        drawPixel(xCentre + x0, yCentre + ((floor((x0 * yShear) / xShear)) + y0));
        drawPixel(xCentre - x0, yCentre + ((floor((x0 * yShear) / xShear)) + y0));
        drawPixel(xCentre + x0, yCentre + ((floor((x0 * yShear) / xShear)) - y0));
        drawPixel(xCentre - x0, yCentre + ((floor((x0 * yShear) / xShear)) - y0));

        if (sigma >= 0)
        {
            sigma += (fourASquared * (1 - y0));
            y0--;
        }

        sigma += (bSquared * ((4 * x0) + 6));
        x0++;
    }

    x0 = widthAxis;
    y0 = 0;
    sigma = (aSquared * 2) + (bSquared * (1 - (2 * widthAxis)));

    while ((aSquared * y0) <= (bSquared * x0))
    {
        drawPixel(xCentre + x0, yCentre + ((floor((x0 * yShear) / xShear)) + y0));
        drawPixel(xCentre - x0, yCentre + ((floor((x0 * yShear) / xShear)) + y0));
        drawPixel(xCentre + x0, yCentre + ((floor((x0 * yShear) / xShear)) - y0));
        drawPixel(xCentre - x0, yCentre + ((floor((x0 * yShear) / xShear)) - y0));

        if (sigma >= 0)
        {
            sigma += (fourBSquared * (1 - x0));
            x0--;
        }

        sigma += (aSquared * (4 * y0) + 6);
        y0++;
    }

    //the above algorithm hasn't been quite completed
    //there are still a few things I want to enquire Andy about
    //before I move on

    //this other algorithm definitely works
    //however
    //it is computationally expensive
    //and the line drawing isn't as refined as the first one
    //only use this as a last resort

/*  std::vector<std::vector <float>> rotate;
    rotate = maths.rotateMatrix(angle, 'z');

    float s = rotate[0][1];
    float c = rotate[0][0];
    float ratio = (float)height / (float)width;
    float px, py, xNew, yNew;

    for (int theta = 0; theta <= 360; theta++)
    {
        px = (xCentre + (cos(maths.degToRad(theta)) * (width / 2))) - xCentre;
        py = (yCentre - (ratio * (sin(maths.degToRad(theta)) * (width / 2)))) -     yCentre;

        x0 = (px * c) - (py * s);
        y0 = (px * s) + (py * c);

        drawPixel(x0 + xCentre, y0 + yCentre);
    }*/
}
```

Here's the problem. When testing the rotation matrix on my oval drawing function, I expect it to draw an ellipse at a slant from its original horizontal position as signified by 'angle'. Instead, it makes a heart shape. This is sweet, but not the result I want.

[image: Result]

I have managed to get the other algorithm (as seen in the bottom part of that code sample) working successfully, but it takes more time to compute, and doesn't draw lines quite as nicely. I only plan to use that if I can't get this Bresenham one working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question that would benefit from a picture.

Comment: @n.m. How's that?